# Recently brought home a 3 week old cockatiel chick, why does my adult male cockatiel keep trying to feed it without feeding anything?

Tags: birds, cockatiels

Does the question make sense? I've adopted an adult male cockatiel (Miu), he's very sweet and tame. We've had him for a few years now. 
Recently my mom brought home a 3 week old cockatiel chick, Miu is very interested and always observes me feeding the baby. Whenever he gets close to the baby, he goes for the mouth straight away as though he is feeding the baby, but I don't see any food coming out. I always take him away because I'm worried that the baby could get sick or the baby's crop is going to be too full if by chance he is actually feeding him. Is this normal behaviour? It's as though he's fostering the baby, but he's bad at it xD.